# How can I find out the capacity of the nfs mounted directory on the disk?

Tags: linux, disk-space, du, df

I cloud not find files filling the disk. df -h command print out / part usage %86 ( capacity is 15G ) but du -sh / command print out 3G.

I am using nfs share on my system. the nfs mounted to /mnt. i remembered i copied to /mnt some files before mount to nfs. nfs share unmounted to /mnt . i can find filling files.

How can I find the files without nfs unmounted.

Thanks for helping Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a temporary mountpoint and run `mount --bind / /mnt2`. This will clone the `/` mount (i.e. the same filesystem will be mounted at two places), but it will *not* clone sub-mounts, so `/mnt2/mnt` will let you access all files that are currently "covered" by the NFS mount.

After cleaning it out, unmount /mnt2 normally.

Comment: The method is working. Also i tested for local disk and SAN disk mounted to local directory.  Thanks  for helping.